# iterables predefinidos: implicaciones con la propiedad length y el operador de acceso []

Tags: javascript, es6

Me preguntaba si todos los iterables predefinidos en JavaScript que tienen la propiedad `.length`, se puede acceder a sus elementos via el operador `[<indice numérico>]` y viceversa?

```
Array -> `.length` & operador `[]`
String -> `.length` & operador `[]`
TypedArray -> `.length` & operador `[]`
Set -> no tiene `.length` & no accede a los elementos iterados via `[]`
Map -> no tiene `.length` & no accede a los elementos iterados via `[]`
HTMLCollection -> `.length` & operador `[]`
```

Encuentro que todos tienen length, se puede acceder a sus elementos iterados via el operador [] y viceversa. Pregunto si hay alguna excepción.

Comment: por Map te refieres a [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)? por que ese prototipo si cuenta con la propiedad `lenght` y se comporta tal cual como si fuese un arreglo ...

Comment: Pareciera como si hicieras una pregunta ya la contestaras. Preguntas si todos cumplen algo y encuentras algunos que no. Ahí tienes la respuesta.

Comment: No, en realidad encuentro que todos cumplen ese algo (todos los que tienen length, se puede acceder a sus elementos iterados via el operador [] y viceversa). Y pregunto si hay alguna excepción.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando `length` es una propiedad de `Object`, `[]` se puede usar en todos los objetos indexables, así que en cuando a excepciones de sobre la posibilidad de usar `length` y `[]` en objetos indexables, no las hay.

Varios de los objetos de los incluídos son objetos globales pero otros no, y algunos son objetos indexados de ECMAScript 6 y otros no. Puedes consultar la lista de objetos globales en varios sitios sobre JavaScript, por ejemplo la página [Objetos Globales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales) de Mozilla Developer Network, o bien directamente en la especificación [ECMAScript 6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

Sobre los objetos citados en la pregunta

- Array es un objeto global del tipo colección indexada.
- String es un objeto global del tipo procesamiento de texto.
- TypedArray no es un objeto global pero sí es un objeto del tipo colección indexada
- Set y Map son objetos globales del tipo colección con llave
- HTMLCollection no forma parte de ECMASCript 6, se trata de una API.

Otros objetos globales indexables son WeakMap y WeakSet.